# What is the best way to reset (re-initialize) a list of integers (to 0) in Python

Tags: python, list, time, reset

Given a list of integers (`list_nb`) of fixed size (`n`), what is the best way to reset (re-initialize) all the values to 0.

I already tried two methods, 1) using a loop to reset all elements one by one, 2) a new list with the same size (where all elements are at 0).

The second method clearly gives better results in terms of execution time.

```
import time

n = 200_000_000
list_nb = [0]*n

# some lines of code that change the list_nb ....

# method 1 to reset
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(len(list_nb)):
    list_nb[i] = 0
end_time = time.time()
print("Method 1 time = ",end_time-start_time," s")

# method 2 to reset
start_time = time.time()
list_nb = [0]*n
end_time = time.time()
print("Method 2 time = ",end_time-start_time," s")
```

Result:

- Method 1 time =  16.05620765686035  s
- Method 2 time =  1.279524564743042  s

I don't know if there is any other way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using numpy is pretty quick.

```
import numpy as np
import time

n= 200000000

start_time = time.time()
list_nb = np.zeros(n)
end_time = time.time()
print(end_time-start_time)
```

This takes me `0.003000497817993164`

Comment: Thanks :) , yes indeed it gives better results (in time of execution).  list_nb = list_nb = np.zeros(size,dtype=int).  Method 1 time =  19.04 s ; Method 2 time =  1.27 s ; Method 3 time =  0.44 s.  Thank you.

Comment: beside it is faster, but it has a drawback, when we want to use it (for example concatenate) with existing list, we have to convert it to list ( (np.zeros(size,dtype=int)).tolist() ), and this gives more time than just creating a new list (method 1).

Answer (score 1):

Method 2 is clearly superior on speed, and it's easy to understand for anyone familiar with Python sequence multiplication. A warning: It's not resetting the *contents* of the `list`; it's making a whole new `list` and *rebinding* the name to that new `list`. So if `list_nb` was an argument to a function, the caller's copy of the `list` would not be changed. If that's what you want, great, but if you want the contents to be changed in place, change it to:

```
list_nb[:] = [0]*n  # Or itertools.repeat(0, n), though CPython doesn't speed it up
```

which uses slice assignment to replace the contents of the existing `list` in-place. It takes about twice as long (it builds a new `list`, copies from it, then throws it away) as `list_nb = [0]*n`, but if you need in-place mutation, it's worth it.

Comment: Thank you very much, yes indeed, it is a very good point (I didn't' thought about it). in terms of Execution time, it gives more than the twice; it is almost the same thing as method 1 (loop over all elements) for this example. if change the size, we see that your proposed method is faster than looping through all elements.

Comment: @ibra: In your original example, method 1 took well over 10x as long as method 2, my "method 3" is only about 2x as long, not "almost the same thing as method 1".

Comment: with the n= 200_000_000 (in my machine) ==> Method 1 (loop) = 15.41   s | Method 2 (new list) =  1.26 s | Method 3 (use numpy) =  0.44 s | Method 4 (your method: uses slice assignment) =  12.77 s  ||  with the n= 300_000_000 ==> Method 1 (loop) = 24.94 s | Method 2 (new list) =  1.88 s | Method 3 (use numpy) =  0.66 s | Method 4 (uses slice assignment) =  19.03 s.   I don't know why in your machin is 2x and mine is about 10x (uses slice assignment vs new list) ! . Thank you very much @ShadowRanger

Comment: Indeed more test, with the same parameter (n=200_000_000 and n=3_0...) and yes i gives 2x times than (new list), You're right :) . But I steel don't understand why the test gives such a different result between 10x and 2x. Thank you very Much :)

Comment: @ibra: I'd recommend using the `timeit.repeat` method rather than using `time`; it gives more reproducible results.

Comment: Ok, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is overwriting the list as you did in method #2. It's easier to overwrite the existing list than replacing every element in the list with 0. I believe there is no faster way to do it, but I might be wrong. Nice job !

Comment: Thank :) , it seem that the solution proposed by @Necklondon and jvieira88 is faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ready to use numpy:

```
start_time = time.time()
a = numpy.zeros(n, dtype=object) 
end_time = time.time()
print("Method 0 time = ",end_time-start_time," s")
```

gives

```
('Method 0 time = ', 0.8265918731689453, ' s')
```

Comment: Thanks :) , yes indeed it gives better results (in time of execution).  I just changed the object by int, a = numpy.zeros(n, dtype=int)

Comment: beside it is faster, but it has a drawback, when we want to use it (for example concatenate) with existing list, we have to convert it to list ( (np.zeros(size,dtype=int)).tolist() ), and this gives more time than just creating a new list (method 1)